# How to send the jquery array value to controller on codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, session

i am new to codeigniter, i was created some list of records from database , my problem is if i want to delete the more record using checkbox , i was get the array value as string format from jquery, but i dont know how to send this value to controller , please tell anyone

my jquery code multi select record

```
$('.del_mybuyer').click(function(){
        var selected = new Array();
        var inc = 0;
        $('input.selbuyer:checked').each(function(){
                selected[inc] = $(this).attr('id'); 
            inc = inc + 1;
        })      
        tdelbuy=selected.toString();                

    })
```

here the tdelbuy was working fine, but i dont know how to set this in session or how to send this to my controller, please tell any one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `$.ajax`, `$.post`, or `$.get`

try this

```
  $.post('path/to /your/controller',{data:tdelbuy},function(html){
        alert(html);
  });
```

and your controller get the posted value by

```
 var postedValue=$this->input->post('data'); 
 //do your stuff.
 echo "done";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the AJAX methods as bipen suggested.  Or, if you prefer not to use AJAX, you can set the value of a hidden input to the value of your javascript variable and post it back with the rest of the form.

```
<form id="your_form" method="POST" action="form.php">
   <!-- your existing form inputs and layouts -->
   <input id="your_hidden_input" name="data" value="" />
</form>
```

And then in your javascript

```
$('.del_mybuyer').click(function(){
    var selected = new Array();
    var inc = 0;
    $('input.selbuyer:checked').each(function(){
            selected[inc] = $(this).attr('id'); 
        inc = inc + 1;
    })      
    tdelbuy=selected.toString();                
    $("#your_hidden_input").val(tdelbuy);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    item = new Array();
    $("input.selbuyer:checked").each(function(index,data ) {
            item[index] = $(this).attr('id'); 
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "your url",
        data: item,
        success:function(data){
          alert(completed);
        }       
    });
```