# How to send an array via the url in javascript/jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, codeigniter

I am trying to send a javascript array via the url.But it fails

```
function viewReport(mode,someid){
    if(mode==0){
        var para= new Array();
        para['para1'] = 'para1'||0;
        para['para2']= 'para2' || 0;
        console.log(para);
        window.open('somePDFView/'+para,'_blank'); 
    }else{
        var para=[];
        var paraelements={
          para1:'anotherpara1'||0,
          para2:'anotherpara2'||0
        };
        para[0]=paraelements;
        window.open('somePDFView/'+para,'_blank'); 
    }
}
```

On `if part(mode=0)`, the para array is not sending any more and on else part (`mode=1`) the
para is sends like this:

```
somePDFView/[object Object]
```

Which shows the error:

> The URI you submitted has disallowed characters

How can we send an array via url.I can't use Ajax (because its a popup window) or session or storing in a temporary table.Also how can we retrieve this value in the controller.

Edit:

I miss an important thing that I am using codeigniter. Then I think it disallows special characters like - &,=,[,],etc..So if any other methods available for sending data as an array?..

Comment: You might want to use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [param](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

Comment: You could encode it. But a URL has a maximum length to send variables I think, so don't make it too long.

Comment: serialize?  k I will study that one and try it...

Comment: Don't use arrays with non-numeric keys!

Comment: I think you should first study why `string + array` produces strange results... *(hint: what happens when you combine a car with an apple?)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To send an array of params via URL from Javascript to PHP/Codeigniter, you need to follow 2 steps:

1. Convert your params array to JSON String and send that as a single query param.

   `para = JSON.stringify(para);`
   `window.open('somePDFView?params='+para,'_blank');`
2. Decode the query string param (i.e JSON string) at your controller

   `$params = json_decode($_GET['params']);`

Now you can use all the params at your controller by accessing through $params.

Your code block becomes:

```
function viewReport(mode,someid){
    if(mode==0){
        var para= new Array();
        para['para1'] = 'para1'||0;
        para['para2']= 'para2' || 0;
        console.log(para);
        para = JSON.stringify(para);
        window.open('somePDFView?params='+para,'_blank'); 
    }else{
        var para=[];
        var paraelements={
          para1:'anotherpara1'||0,
          para2:'anotherpara2'||0
        };
        para[0]=paraelements;
        para = JSON.stringify(para);
        window.open('somePDFView?params='+para,'_blank'); 
    }
}
```

Try this out and let me know if you still faces this issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `Json` here. Use `JSON.stringify()`.

**Note:** 
Don't sent long data over a URL. There is a limit for sending data via url and it will end up in a corrupted data if exceeded the limit. For large data, use `POST` method.

```
function viewReport(mode,someid){
    var json;
    if(mode==0){
        var para= new Array();
        var paraelements={
      para1:'para1'||0,
      para2:'para2'||0
    };
    para[0]=paraelements;
    json = JSON.stringify(para);
    window.open('somePDFView/'+json,'_blank'); 
    }else{


 var para=[];
    var paraelements={
      para1:'anotherpara1'||0,
      para2:'anotherpara2'||0
    };
    para[0]=paraelements;
    json = JSON.stringify(para);
    window.open('somePDFView/'+json,'_blank'); 
  }
}
```

If you are using php, use `json_decode()` to convert json into PHP variable.Also refer, 
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Its also showing the error --The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: Use console.log(json) and check what data is being return before sending through url.

Comment: the data is correctly assigned and json contains all that values but it can't send

Comment: Are you sending the data by using query string?

Comment: Sorry I miss a important thing.I am using codeigniter, so i think it does not allows  special characters like &,=,[,].Is it right?

Comment: And make sure that the popup window is not blocked in your browser you used.

Comment: popup window is not blocked....how can we send data as an array in jquery when using codeigniter?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362632/how-to-send-the-jquery-array-value-to-controller-on-codeigniter

Comment: Sorry that one uses ajax.I am very thankful for your kind replays.Anyway I will not convert it into an array ,instead sending one by one or using a temporary table.But what the team lead will say .:(

Answer (score 3):

You can try to pass them as individual parameters:

```
var para1 = '1';
var para2 = '2';
var para= new Array();
para.push('para[]=' + para1 || 0);
para.push('para[]=' + para2 || 0);
var url = para.join('&');
alert(url)
```

Returns `para[]=1&para[]=2`. Note that this solution does not require `jQuery`.

Comment: Now i can see the parameters on url--salesexePDFView/parat[] = 1&parat[] = 2 but it shows The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: I removed the spaces between `parat[]` and the `=` sign. It should work now.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)** and change your data structure :

```
var para = {
    para1:'anotherpara1'||0,
    para2:'anotherpara2'||0
};

window.open('somePDFView/'+jQuery.param(para), '_blank');
```

The **[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4CYw/1/)**

Comment: You can't do this. See this [tread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427479/programmatically-open-new-pages-on-tabs).